# Strange java jvm outofmemory

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have an application running under jboss5. It has a user login side as well as background quartz jobs. One background job makes a soap call and pull down a large object to parse. It uses a good amount of memory.

I see a pattern of when I get an OOM exception like this:

```
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (QuartzScheduler_Scheduler-NON_CLUSTERED_MisfireHandler) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-80-9) Exception in thread "http-0.0.0.0-80-9" 
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-80-9) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Session Monitor) Exception in thread "Session Monitor" 
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Monitor Runner) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Monitor Runner)     at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Monitor Runner)     at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:329)
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Monitor Runner)     at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
2013-06-04 21:44:36,855 ERROR [STDERR] (Monitor Runner)     at com.icesoft.util.MonitorRunner$1.run(MonitorRunner.java:54)
```

This job runs nightly. When nobody is using the UI for days, I'll get the OOM after a few days. But when people use the UI application daily, I can go for over a month or more and never see the OOM problem.

It seems like there is something good that happens when the application is used, but I have no idea what. Does anyone have an idea of where to start looking and what to try?

We're using jdk 1.7.0.11 and javaopts are

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xrs -Xms256M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC "
```

Thank you,

Jim

Comment: Relevant code would help

Comment: It seems some memory leak in code. I would suggest use something like VisualVM to identify objects in memory and related code.

Comment: Still it is best practice to manually assign null references after using the objects and leaving the activity , like if you are using some Arraylist<Object> give it null reference in onDestroy of your activity .Sometime this can be helpful to solve memory issues .

Comment: It crashes when running the javax.xml.transform.Transformer transform() method. The ArrayLists above are nested in the transform() method. It pulls a big REST XML file it has to parse. But why would it never throw OOM if users are interactive in the UI and will OOM if nobody uses the app?

Comment: Also, this routine fires off out of quartz nightly. It references spring beans to get DB persistence, then makes the xml callout. So I can't see any reason why it would not be GC'd when it ends. It will succeed 3-7 nights in a row (variable), then crash.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` JVM argument then open the Heap Dump in MAT. MAT will show you the suspects of the OOM, you can even walk through the heap yourself and identify which objects occupy the most of the heap. This way you can easily find the culprit of the problem.

Also, it would help enabling GC logging so you can see if there are any patterns that lead to the OOM.